# Tridion experience manager SAX error

Tags: content-delivery, experience-manager

Ladies and gents I am setting up Tridion Experience manager. Everything seems to be working fine ... but ;) Trying to refresh the preview or the automatic update after an edit using the experience manager I recieve a SAX error. Fiddler is was so kind to provide me with the information that:

```
/WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetPreviewToken
```

Is returning this SAX error

> The input data could not be parsed: SAXException occured while trying
>   to parse the input xml., XML document structures must start and end
>   within the same entity.,  XML document structures must start and end
>   within the same entity.,  SAXException occured while trying to parse
>   the input xml., XML document structures must start and end within the
>   same entity., XML document structures must start and end within the
>   same entity., SAXException occured while trying to parse the input
>   xml., XML document structures must start and end within the same
>   entity., XML document  structures must start and end within the same
>   entity.

I am looking for some clue as to where to start looking what/who is causing this error.

*Updated 2013-03-20*

Fiddler is showing the SAX error on:

> /WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetPreviewToken

## Core Logging staging server

> 2013-03-20 14:31:10,443 DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: null
>
> 2013-03-20 14:32:39,937 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
>
> 2013-03-20 14:32:39,953 DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext
>
> 2013-03-20 14:32:40,219 ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while validating file 'cd_ambient_conf.xml' with schema 'schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd'. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ClaimStoreProvider'. One of '{Cookies}' is expected.

Seems indeed I have misconfigured the Ambientdata stuff. Though I have copied from the sample conf files and edited like the UI Update manual says. Here are the confs:

## Ambient Conf

### Preview web

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="6.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">
    <Cartridges>
        <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
        <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
    </Cartridges>
<ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>
</Configuration>
```

### Preview Webservice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="6.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">
    <Cartridges>
        <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
    </Cartridges>
</Configuration>
```

Kind regards,
Ryan.

Comment: Did you look into the Preview WebService logs? Try to set them to TRACE, restart your WebService, perform your test and check the generated logs to see if an error is there.

Comment: one thing that bit me once: could you in your templates try to put any XPM specific markup on a single line

Comment: @Ryan - I am also facing this error on the home page of my website, all other pages are working fine after clicking Update Preview. Could you pls guide me on how you fixed the error.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange.

I suspect that this may be to do with the Ambient Data Framework filters.  Nuno has given more information on the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788508/continously-update-preview-alert-on-sdl-tridion-ui-2012).

The 'Architecture' section of Ryan's UI 2012 Overview [here](http://blog.building-blocks.com/sdl-tridion-user-interface-2012-overview) may help too.

Hope it helps, Jon

**[UPDATE 26/03/2013]**

Albert's ["Troubleshooting the SDL Tridion Experience Manager with Session Preview"](http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/) article is very useful.  On top of this, it can also be helpful to use Fiddler or the Firebug NET tab to view the requests that are being made from the browser when working with Experience Mananger

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, Nuno's posts overview over the sequence of events was very helpful.

Comment: Have you solved the problem, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by removing out the javascript comments from the javascript component which where added as component presentation on the page.